# Opinion on puzzle-series tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging, retagging

We have had several discussions on puzzle-series and common names in titles, the [most recent one here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1747/can-we-remove-or-combine-puzzles-covering-multiple-posts).

Now, I would like to propose that we introduce *series-xxx* tags for puzzle series. 
The main reason, why puzzle-series have "common names" is to allow easier identification and search, but I think this could be achieved much easier and better with tags

For example, I really think that the "Ernie" themed puzzles deserve a "**series-Ernie**" tag to have them easily listed next to each other and even do things like RSS feeds or news-alerts should a new one be posted.

I think such *series-xxx* tags should be used sparingly and only if at least 3 puzzles *really* belong together (and not only by the same author), but if used with common sense, I can only see them doing good. They all should be *series-xxx* with *xxx* being series-identifying so that they can be easily spotted.

Opinions on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since meta-tags are bad but searchability is good, any writer who wants can put in a searchable line after each puzzle in the series. For example,

*This is part of the [Ernie series of puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20%22This%20is%20part%20of%20the%20Ernie%20series%20of%20puzzles.%22).*

with a link to the search result.

Comment: Good suggestion, I like that.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, that would be a meta tag. It describes certain aspects of the puzzle, not the content of the puzzle itself.

It's also worthless in categorizing and promoting the discovery of questions, which is the entire point of tags in the first place. Let's say there's a puzzle called a "Steve puzzle" in which the protagonist Steve has to solve various [logic-grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-grid) puzzles. What is the purpose of having a [steve](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steve) tag which, to a new user, describes exactly nothing about the post's content, rather than a much more useful [logic-grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-grid) tag? How could one possibly be an expert in these "[steve](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steve)" puzzles without also being an expert in [logic-grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-grid), and vice versa? These types of tags would add no practical value to the site.

Answer (score -4):

As the response to Doorknob's answer would be too big for a comment, I'm putting it here.

Doorknob, I simply don't think I fully agree with your statements.

---

Let's first deal with your example question:

> *"...Let's say there's a puzzle called a "Steve puzzle" in which the protagonist Steve has to solve various [logic-grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-grid) puzzles. What is the purpose of having a [steve](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steve) tag which, to a new user, describes exactly nothing about the post's content, rather than a much more useful [logic-grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-grid) tag?"*...

1. First, I would propose that the appropriated question tagging would be [logic-grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-grid) **and** [series-steve](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series-steve). It should of course be possible to find the puzzle when looking for logic-grid puzzles, but it should *also* be possible to find all puzzles of this ingenious Steve-series which I know is my level of hardness, has unique but fair twists and is *just what I'm looking for*.
2. Have you noticed that `Puzzle SE` is *different* from say `Earth Science SE`? 
   (*No, this is not meant as a provocative statement, but to highlight the argument below.*) 
    The questions *rarely* have an *object* they are about and which is tagged. Instead, most of them are challenges which *are* of a certain category, which is tagged. Hence tags like [logic-grid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-grid) *are* a sort of meta-tag already! They describe a primary property of the *question* not a property of the object the question is about. 
   (The currently most used tag [cryptic-crosswords](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptic-crosswords) is used in questions which *are* cryptic-crosswords and not if they ask *about* cryptic-crosswords.)
   The proposed [series-xxx](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series-xxx) tag would *also* describe a property of the question, namely a 2nd (3rd, 4th...) 'category' it belongs to. The difference being, that this 'category' is not generally known outside the site. Hence the mandatory *series-* in front of it, to make it such. Granted, series tags  are useless *outside* the StackExchange, i.e. it is not a tag one would Google for, but that is not the purpose of tags, is it?
3. > *"...These types of tags would add no practical value to the site."*

   This is the statement I most severely disagree with. The whole purpose of this question here is , that it came about *because* it  (might) solve an existing problem - which I would define as adding value. 
   So lets put prejudices against "meta"-tags aside for a moment and examine what *could* be done with the proposed tags. Afterwards examine the "dangers" associated with them compared to the other tags we already use.

   We undoubtedly *have* content on this site which by one or the other means should be *grouped* together for easier reference. I think the best serving example (also because of the outstanding quality) are the [Penguino's](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1631/penguino) *Ernie-themed* puzzles. Looking at them, is there any doubt that they *should* be grouped together for easier reference/finding?

   Right now, the grouping in done by a common `"Ernie and the..."` title. I think it has already been [agreed on](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1747/can-we-remove-or-combine-puzzles-covering-multiple-posts) that *grouping-by-title* is problematic. "Ernie and" might be a rather unique catch-phrase, but searching by title-parts is surely not a good thing in general. It is too easy to get results which do *not* belong to a series, and if multiple questions use *identical* titles (except for numbers), it becomes even worse.

   Alternatively, one could only search author, but this is a very poor substitute also. No guarantee that all puzzles of a series are done by one author, or that one author only has questions belonging to a series.

   So, as an argument *against* a [series-xxx](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series-xxx) tag, **how else *could* we solve this issue?**

   > If there is an elegant solution, I'm the first to abolish the idea of series-tagging. But if there is *no* other elegant solution, I think this tagging *would add value* and it rather remains a question of *how* should it be done than *if* it should be done.

   Now were are the problems? **We do not want to promote meta-tagging.** I think, this is what it boils down to. Doorknob's reaction is very much understandable if one considers that he's a moderator and therefore in constant battle with bad meta-tagging. So this series-tagging should be introduced in a way which minimizes/eliminates bad side-effects.

   We clearly **do not want:**

   - Authors tagging all their puzzles as [series-username](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series-username)
   - Series-tags as disguise for meta-(meta-)tags like [series-high-quality](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series-high-quality)
   - Hundredths of 'mini-series' of 2 or 3 posts.
   - ... ?

   I think we can 'battle' this from the start by enforcing some **simple rules for [series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series) tags**:

   - Series tags are **created & edited in *after* a series has been identified by the community**.
      As such, a series needs to have at least 3 *existing* and approved of (positively scored) member questions.
   - There has to be a **real communality within the series *on top of* a common puzzle category and/or authorship**.
   - **No other tagging could achieve the same** grouping **effect**.
   - General tag requirements (Wiki , scrutiny by community etc.) apply

Comment: I think there *is* doubt that questions should be grouped in series. If one question *builds on* an earlier one then it should link back to the earlier one in its text. If the questions are independent and linked only by the fictional setting (~= the text which could be stripped away without losing the actual puzzle), I don't see any benefit to grouping them. This is a puzzle site: the relationships between puzzles which should matter to the site are those which are inherent to the puzzles: i.e. the mechanics.

Comment: Clear statement, thanks. (I differ in my opinion though.)

Comment: In particular, your first point (which I summarise as "*I want to find puzzles from the same series because I know they're the kind of puzzle I want to solve*") only makes sense if the link between the puzzles in the series is mechanical, and in that case a tag which describes the mechanic is both beneficial and sufficient.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Not true. I like f.e. the Ernies because I know they are *well made* and even if complex, *worth solving*. (They are not all of the same mechanics) Or: I might like *some* riddles while I don't like *all* riddles.

Comment: But how do you go about guaranteeing that anything tagged with series-ernie has the hard-to-define properties you like? Isn't that really a case of knowing that you like Penguino's puzzles? It may be the case that there's "*no guarantee that all puzzles of a series are done by one author*", but I don't think you've made an argument to support the idea that in that case there's a genuine non-mechanical commonality that's worth tagging. Do you have any examples of series by multiple authors which you think need a non-mechanical tag?