# Linking to your own questions

Tags: discussion

I was wondering what the thought/rules on linking/chaining together your own questions from the same category (but possibly unrelated) for Puzzling are(if any)?

I.E: If you have made 3 rhyming riddles, and you are creating a 4th, should you be allowed to have your first riddle have a link to your second, and second to third, and third to fourth (and/or vise-versa)?

The reasoning behind doing something like this would be to allow people that liked the question to be able to look/browse at your other similar questions more easily [since they already enjoy the initial one, they might enjoy the others].

One downside to this (on the posters behalf), is that they will have a larger post, with links which might take away from the puzzle (and might become out of hand if misused). Another downside is that for every new post that someone links, both their new and old post will be bumped up on the active list from being modified/created.

I would like to know if there are any rules/thoughts either for or against this as I was thinking of implementing it for some of my riddles and lateral thinking questions.

Comment: [Related.](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/2781/4551)

Comment: @xnor I notice that post/chain is talking about linking questions to  tags to (link puzzles). Do you know any meta information about post directly linking to other posts for reference?

Comment: No, I don't know of any references or precedent.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/community-consensus-on-linked-puzzles)?

Comment: @randal'thor yes, however my question seems to be more concerned with a broader (personal) correlation oppose to a puzzle series relation. [But still helpful]

Comment: Great question Mark. I had wondered the same thing, but didn't think to ask.

Answer (score 7):

As [I suggested before](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2781/4551), I think the best approach is for the author to include an unobtrusive link to a search for puzzles in the series:

> *This is part of the [Ernie series of puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=Ernie+user%3A1631+is%3Aquestion).*

Linking to the search means you don't have to manually update whenever you add a new puzzle. It also gives the reader options like sorting by votes or filtering by keywords, which would not be available with links to puzzles.

I would ask authors to use discretion and only to link to puzzles in a series or sharing a theme or style, and not just to advertise all their puzzles.

Comment: I've edited the link because the search wasn't working. Now it should be fine for everyone, I hope.

Comment: Just to clarify for future people. An example search template [look at 'Advanced Search Tips'] would be: "[riddle] user:me" - where me will be replaced with your user number, and the tag riddle is used.

Comment: @MarkN I had been thinking more specifically to search for the tagline quote, so that it results only in puzzles marked with that tagline.

Comment: Great suggestion! I am glad I came across this post!